# Google maps v3: Define info window shape

Tags: google-maps

I was wondering if there's a way to change the default shape of a google.maps.InfoWindow object.

[image: Default info window]

I just want to display a rectangle in the center of the map with some HTML content (I don't want the dialog-like shape.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the size like this,

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
              { 
                size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
              });
```

or you can use google maps infobox api.http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox.js